# DLL, no aparecen sus metodos y/o clases en referencia

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

Agregue una referencia dll de un proyecto class Lybrary asp Core en otro proyecto para pruebas pero no me aparecen las clases que se implementaron ni agregando namespace using (Visual studio 2017), como ver esas clases?o tiene algo que ver el compilado en framework core 1.0?

Comment: Te muestra algun error?

Comment: Algunas dll's no son compatibles con .net core. Es posible que eso sea lo que te está pasando.

Comment: Necesitas agregar mas detalles, con lo que comentas no podemos tener una idea clara de como proporcionarte una respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Despues de buscar un poco, encontre la respuesta ya que en asp core se crea otro ensamblado del mismo nombre pero dentro de carpeta bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1 dependiendo la version instalada, esa dll es la correcta!Soy nuevo en asp.core y espero le sirva alguien,,..saludos!